# How to present server ready data (REST,JPA and relationships) on the client side using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

Since I am new to AngularJS I have come across an issue when it comes to presenting my database data which has been mapped using Rest and manipulated using JPA. So it is as ready as it can be. No need for further manipulation. Now using the $http.get I have been able to present the first table just calling the url but when it comes to getting data presented from a different table by sending a parameter something doens't work out. 
In the module.js it looks like this

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app',[]);

})();
```

The controller.js like this:

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('MyController', MyController);

    MyController.$inject = ['$http'];

    function MyController($http) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.players = [];
        vm.historia = [];
        vm.getAll = getAll;
        vm.getHistory = getHistory;

        init();

        function init(){
            getAll();
            getHistory(name);
        }

        function getAll(){
            var url = "/all/players";
            var playersPromise = $http.get(url);
            playersPromise.then(function(response){
                vm.players = response.data;
            });
        }

        function getHistory(name){
            var url = "/all/allplayergames/" + name;
            var historiaPromise = $http.get(url);
            console.log([url]);
            historiaPromise.then(function(response){
                vm.historia = response.data;
                console.log([response.data]);
            });
        }

    }
})();
```

and last but not least html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Game</title>
    <link th:if="${mode=='development'}"  rel="stylesheet" href="../static/bootstrap.css" th:href="@{/bootstrap.css}"/>
    <link th:if="${mode=='production'}"  rel="stylesheet" href="../static/bootstrap.min.css" th:href="@{/bootstrap.min.css}"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/angular.min.js" th:src="@{/angular.min.js}" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/app/app.module.js" th:src="@{/app/app.module.js}" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/app/yatzy.controller.js" th:src="@{/app/yatzy.controller.js}" ></script>
    </head>
<body ng-app="app" >

<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Game Results</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8">
           <div ng-controller="MyController as vm">
               <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                   <button ng-click="vm.getAll()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Player Game History</button>
               </div>
            <table  class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>PlayerID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>

                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="player in vm.players">
                <td> {{player.playerid}}</td>
                <td> {{player.name}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="vm.getHistory(player.name);
">View History</button>
                    </td>

                </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>



            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Score</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="p in vm.historia">

                    <td> {{p.score}}</td>
                    <td> {{p.player.name}}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
           </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<footer class="footer" style="position: absolute; bottom: 0;background-color: #f5f5f5;" >
    <div class="container">
        <p  th:text="${#dates.format(datetime,'dd MMM yyyy HH:mm')}" class="text-muted">Todays date: </p>
    </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

And the console log does show the right player url when the "View History" is clicked, but it doesnt get the data from the table that is the score or the name.

Comment: what is "name" in your controller.js ?

Comment: the parameter im trying to send via the url in order for it to return a list of objects from the database on the server side where name equals a certain player like name=John

Comment: I didn't find any value assigned to the variable name(Correct me if i am wrong). So ideally, name will be "undefined". Please assign a value to this variable.

Comment: it gets assigned when clicking the button View History,  <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="vm.getHistory(player.name);
">View History</button>

Comment: @Em.C: can u create a fiddle?

Comment: Well in that case, first check the value for name(write console.log inside getHistory function). Check whether its undefined or not. In case not, check the response. You can do that either using console, which you have already done, or checking the network tab. Check if data is coming is coming or not. It might happen that you are getting an empty array i.e. no data to display.

Comment: I wrote in my post that im getting a result in the console.log with the url and the right name and one player in the array, meaning it is returning but not the values, just the right url. So the array is not empty.

Comment: Ok. Can you post a sample response data ?

Comment: Array[1]0: "/all/allplayergames/Tomte"length: 1__proto__: Array[0]
yatzy.controller.js:42 Array[1]0: Array[1]length: 1__proto__: Array[0]

Comment: @Em.C : So the response containing the data, or its response.data that holds the data. Check for that please.